# How to fit an array of buttons in a linear layout perfectly

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an alarm clock app in which users select days in a week in which alarm will go off. For that I am using 7 toggle buttons inside a linear layout. And What I expect to see is this [image]

But I'm only seeing this in tablet layouts. For many phone layouts I am seeing this

[image]

That is last button is not visible, buttons are not properly aligned and have newline. How to fix this? My xml code **[EDITED]**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButtonmon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textOff="Mon"
        android:textOn="Mon" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButtontue"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textOff="Tue"
        android:textOn="Tue" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButtonwed"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Wed"
        android:textOn="Wed"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButtonthu"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Thu"
        android:textOn="Thu"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="0dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButtonfri"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Fri"
        android:textOn="Fri"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

     <ToggleButton
         android:id="@+id/toggleButtonsat"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textOff="Sat"
         android:textOn="Sat" 
         android:layout_width="0dp"/>

     <ToggleButton
         android:id="@+id/toggleButtonsun"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textOff="Sun"
         android:textOn="Sun"
         android:layout_width="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly add `android:orientation="horizontal"` to your `LinearLayout`.
Secondly - set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for each `ToggleButton` in order for the weight attribute to take effect.

Comment: Also make sure every `ToggleButton` has `android:layout_weight="1"`. Above, the _Friday_ button does not contain it.

Comment: ok did all that.Sunday button is now visible but still newline is coming, and also not aligned.

Comment: @PradipPramanick Most probably the issue is that the text is too large for the button size, try reducing the text size. `android:textSize="10sp"`

Comment: @Dimitri Thanks. That works. but text and buttons look very small in large screens which is not acceptable. Any way to auto fit?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way of resizing text based on button size. However, you can define different text sizes for different screens by extracting the textSize value to a dimens.xml. Here is a handy guide http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters